# How can I stack 2D arrays along an axis to make a 3D array in an h5 file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

Most of the solutions online either concatenate two 3-dimensional arrays.
What I'm looking for is possibly an empty 3D array and then keep adding 2D arrays(each of the same dimensions) along any axis.

For example, initially, we have  X as an h5 file dataset

```py
X = [[[]]]
```

```py
A = [[1, 1]
      [1, 1]
      [1, 1]
      [1, 1]
      [1, 1]]

# appending A to X

X = [[[1, 1]
      [1, 1]
      [1, 1]
      [1, 1]
      [1, 1]]]

# then we have another (5,2) array say

B = [[2, 2]
      [2, 2]
      [2, 2]
      [2, 2]
      [2, 2]]

# append B to X we get

X = [[[1, 1]
      [1, 1]
      [1, 1]
      [1, 1]
      [1, 1]], 
     [[2, 2]
      [2, 2]
      [2, 2]
      [2, 2]
      [2, 2]]]
```

It would have been easy to just stack two such 2d arrays but, I wanna keep adding 2D arrays in X, in such a way that dimensions of x and y-axis remain the same but z keeps growing.

Is this even possible in Python?

Comment: If you make `A` and `B` numpy arrays. `numpy.stack([A,B])` does what you want.

Comment: If not concatenate or vstack or hstack, then use `np.append`

Comment: I could but, I need to start with an empty array since I'm planning to store the data in h5 file dataset.

Comment: It's most efficient to collect all arrays in a list, and do one `np.array`, `np.stack` or `np.vstack` as appropriate.  Iteratively making a new array for each addition requires a lot more copying.  But where does `h5` come in to the question?